# Is it necessary to write the annotation (.java) when I try to run my java program in the terminal?

Tags: java

Usually, we compile a java program using the `javac` keyword and then run it with the `java` keyword.
But in my case, if I just type `java Main.java`, it runs without any problems.

But if I try to run the program the conventional way:

1. `javac Main.java`
2. `java Main`

it returns an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Is this supposed to happen? I had learnt the conventional method.

I have set *IntelliJ* as the default application for opening `.class` and `.main` files.

Comment: I am new to programming, so please use easy-to-understand words.

Comment: The reason that `java Main.java` works, is that in recent Java versions (from Java 11 onwards) you can execute a single-file source, skipping the compiling step.

Comment: Are you sure, in your ```Main.java``` file, class name is ```Main```?

Comment: @MCEmperor I think you are right there. I use Java 14. Thanks!
But how come the error?

Answer (score 0):

After you compile your code, you end up with .class files.  These binary files are the bytecode that Java interprets to execute your program.

NoClassDefFoundError indicates that the classloader, which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the .class file for the class that you're trying to use.

In order to solve this error, you must know how Java finds and loads the classes,
you just remember that there is an environment variable called CLASSPATH which includes directories where Java looks for all class files and if it doesn't find your main class there then it throws "Error: Could not find or load main class XXX", where XXX is the name of your main class.

For example, if you had a class com.example., after compiling you would have a class file sensor.class. Say for example your working directory is .../project/. That class file must be placed in .../project/com/example, and you would set your classpath to .../project/

Example:-

`C:\project\practice\Main.class` on my computer.

`C:\project\practice\` will it run? No, it will not run it will give you:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test
Since the name of the class is not Main, instead it’s practice.Main even though your classpath is set to the current directory.

Now, what will happen if I give command java practice.Main from C:\project\practice\ it will again not run and give an error?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: practice/Main

Why because now it looking for a class called Main which is in package practice, starting from current directory "." but don't find it since there is no directory called "practice after this path "C:\project\practice".

To run it successfully you need to go back to directory  C:\project and now run
C:\project>java practice.Main  and It will run successfully